# how to connect only ethernet and only wireless hosts together

Tags: wireless-router, ethernet, android, wireless-access-point

Here is my problem. I have an android tablet that have only WiFi for network connectivity and I have a windows server that have only Ethernet ports for network connection. Now I want to telnet to my server from my tablet. I think some wireless to Ethernet converter required in between. I am planning to use Buffalo Air Station WCR-GN or TP-LINK TL-WR740N or TL-WR702N. The connection setup should be like this:
[server]<---Ethernet--->[WIFI router]<---wireless--->[Tablet].

Now I am in doubt will this setup work? Anybody please help me with this.

Regards
Ashok

Comment: This is precisely what a wireless router is for.

Answer (score 1):

Typically your wired pc will plug into a router that also has wireless capability.  In that case, it will bridge between your tablet and pc without any special effort on your part.

Comment: Yup, although not sure I agree with the term bridge, as they are then on the same network / subnet / vlan... so its the same as being on any network together no bridging required.

Comment: The router has to retransmit all the traffic from one to the other, so that's bridging in my book.

Comment: I would stick to the standard definition: *Network bridging describes the action taken by network equipment to allow two or more communication networks, or two or more network segments,[1] to create an aggregate network. Bridging is distinct from routing which allows the networks to communicate independently as separate networks.[2] A network bridge is a network device that connects more than one network segment. In the OSI model bridging acts in the first two layers, below the network layer.[3]*

Answer (score 0):

There is no real weirdness to this, actually. Essentially, what you need as far as a network is:

[image: Dia Topology mockup]

Where the internet comes in to your modem, then to your router.

If you leave the router at defaults, then DHCP will dynamically assign each device a different IP on the same network.

You should be able at this point to ping each device (Android ping search the Play store for *ifconfig*, and or *Ping* as many ifconfig apps also do pinging, and you need ifconfig anyway to get your devices IP).

If you can ping both ways, try telnet. If it fails, then check your firewall and security settings on the desktop.

This should be possible to setup in under 10 minutes, for ~$40 for a cheap wireless router.